# Determine the Largest Value from the Output

Tags: java

I am a beginner at Java attempting this exercise I found online that works according to the logic of the Collatz Sequence. It displays the correct output based upon the entered starting number. It also displays the number of steps in the process.

However, the last part of the exercise asks to determine the largest value from the output.

I'm not sure how to do this with my current beginner knowledge of Java (I only have learned and practiced up until while and do while loops - started a few weeks ago). This is my code so far that I have worked hard on. :D I want to finish this and learn how to determine the maximum value. Thanks! [**Collatz Sequence Exercise**](https://programmingbydoing.com/a/collatz-sequence.html)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollatzSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number, steps = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a number ~ ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println(number);
        do {
            steps++;
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                number = number / 2;
                System.out.println(number);
            }
            else {
                number = (3 * number) + 1;
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        } while (number != 1);

        System.out.println("\nThis took " + steps + " steps.");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can keep track of a variable `maxNumber`. Initialize it to number:

```
 System.out.print("Enter a number ~ ");
 number = keyboard.nextInt();
 maxNumber = number;
```

In your loop, test if the current number is higher, if so , replace the maxNumber with number.

```
...
    if (number > maxNumber) { 
        maxNumber = number;
    }
} while (number != 1);
```

And print it, because you want to know it:

```
 System.out.println(String.format("\nThis took %d steps. Max was: %d", steps , maxNumber));
```

Comment: Enter a number ~ 6
6
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1

This took 8 steps.
The largest value is 16.

Comment: Good Solution but it has runtime errors :) .  If I do your change in the OP's code and give the input as `0`, It went to infinite loop.

Comment: @Thanga yes that is a problem :) @camelCoder should validate the input to be `>0`.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will do the Max number calculation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollatzSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number = 0, steps = 0;
        int maxVal;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive number ~ ");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
            maxVal = number;    
            System.out.println(number);
        } while (number <= 0);

        do {
            steps++;
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                number = number / 2;
            }
            else {
                number = (3 * number) + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(number);
            if (number > maxVal) { 
              maxVal = number;
            }
        } while (number != 1);

        System.out.println("\nThis took " + steps + " steps.");

        System.out.println("\nMax Number is  " + maxVal);

    }
}
```

Comment: if (number % 2 == 0) {
 number = number / 2;
 System.out.println(number);
}
else {
 number = (3 * number) + 1;
 System.out.println(number);
}

In this segment of code, can I write ‘System.out.println(number);’ just once after the if and else? Is that preferred since it’s less code?

Comment: @camelCoder  this program was going infinite loop for 0 and lesser numbers. Please find the fix in my answer